# Template Error: The template file must be given (or the template could not be opened)

Tags: windows, templates, web, hosting

Please I need help, Ive asked my web hoster but no help. only on my laptop. I get Template Error: The template file must be given (or the template could not be opened). dont know how to fit it. I cant get on my dashbroad too. dont understand how only on my laptop works on everything else. hope you can help 
kind regards
john